# Perfoming calculations on properties from different edges in OrientDB

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

I have this unique problem where I want to make calculations from values returned by different edges and it doesn't seem like it's working for me.

My graph's function is to track people's collections of Magic: the Gathering cards. Please use the graph as an illustration for my problem.

[image: graph]

I wanted to take `#8:0` as a starting point and see which decks (`MDeck`) had the cards (`MCard`) I owned and calculate what percentage of the deck I already have in my collection. My query started out like this:

```
SELECT FROM (SELECT FLATTEN(out[label="has"]) FROM #8:0) WHERE in.in.size() > 1
```

This is to get the cards that I owned that belonged to decks. Next if I had more of a certain card than what is required on a deck I would only count what is required, so I had to use MIN(). This is where the problem arises:

```
SELECT
MIN(UNION(in.in[label="includes"].qty, qty))
FROM (
    SELECT
    FLATTEN(out[label="has"])
    FROM #8:0
)
WHERE in.in.size() > 1
```

I thought this will do the trick but it just returned null. I made sure all the qty fields are integers. Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Ramon

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a public database where to execute queries with the OrientDB console or Studio?

If not could you report here the intermediate results of the last query? For example:

```
SELECT
in.in[label="includes"].qty
FROM (
    SELECT
    FLATTEN(out[label="has"])
    FROM #8:0
)
WHERE in.in.size() > 1
```

And then:

```
SELECT
UNION(in.in[label="includes"].qty, qty)
FROM (
    SELECT
    FLATTEN(out[label="has"])
    FROM #8:0
)
WHERE in.in.size() > 1
```

Comment: i have all this on my local. first query gives me two result sets of 4 and 4. second query gives me two result sets of [1,4] and [1,4]. i wanted to find a way to use `in.in[label="includes"].qty` whenever `@this.qty` is bigger than it.